Why model parameters are empty?
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tp

# Importing imdb dataset
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
# The sequence module in tensorflow.keras.preprocessing provides utilities for preprocessing sequence data, such as text or time-series data.

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
# The sequence module in tensorflow.keras.preprocessing provides utilities for preprocessing sequence data, such as text or time-series data.

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, SimpleRNN, Dense

# Define the model
model = Sequential()

# Add the Embedding layer
model.add(Embedding(1000, 128))  # Adjust the vocabulary size (1000) as needed

# Print the summary of the model to check the parameters
model.summary()

# Add the SimpleRNN layer
model.add(SimpleRNN(128, activation='relu'))

# Add the Dense output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Print the model layers
print(model.layers)

# Print the summary to check the parameters
model.summary()

I am trying to create a model using simpleRNN. What is the issue here? I get trainable params as 0:
 Total params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)


Your code run fine on my computer (Total params: 161,025). Check your configuration.

The Keras model summary focuses on the overall architecture and the connections between layers, not the internal workings of each layer. Therefore, the parameters of the SimpleRNN layer are not explicitly listed as separate entities in the summary.

You need to compile the model with an optimizer and loss function, and then train it on your data to see the parameters.
